# browser requests not completing

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a django app served with uwsgi and nginx. This app has been deployed for 8 years and now we are seeing that browser requests do not complete. This is what we see in the request timing tab:

[image]

ss shows only 3 connections to the origin. In the uwsgi log it appears the request has completed:

```
{address space usage: 10855825408 bytes/10352MB} {rss usage: 560128000 bytes/534MB} [pid: 3279260|app: 0|req: 1/25] 10.240.0.58 () {46 vars in 1033 bytes} [Wed Mar 15 13:05:09 2023] GET /report/TASKS/BatchDashboard/ => generated 457971 bytes in 5765 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 6 headers in 327 bytes (4 switches on core 0)
```

There are no errors in the nginx or django logs.

Any thoughts on why this is suddenly happening and/or how I can debug or fix this?

Comment: This has happened to me some times when the nginx server has configured a maximum request time. After that time it stops the request and there is no result. Check if it always fails after 6 seconds

Comment: It always happens between 5 and 6 seconds, but we have the timeouts set to 6000.         proxy_read_timeout, proxy_connect_timeout, proxy_send_timeout, uwsgi_read_timeout, uwsgi_connect_timeout, uwsgi_send_timeout, send_timeout - all set to 6000.

Comment: Can't you do a test and increase the time to 10 seconds for example and then we can rule out the problem on the server side?

Comment: It is already set to 6000 seconds. Or are you talking about some other param?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was 6000ms. To test, I would try to create a log(if not possible, a print would be enough) just before your view returns the response to check if it really just processed the request where you expect or it is doing the return somewhere else.